# Out of Memory heap in AWT/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, out-of-memory, awt, overlay

I have a fullscreen overlay with 3 different photos. I'm storing `BufferedImage` instances in ArrayList, and switch between photos using `CardLayout` listeneing to `KeyEvent`s (reacting to pressing arrow keys).

When I test this overlay isolated, it works just fine.

But when I open it as part of my application, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
        at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
        at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
        at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:331)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.makeBufferedImage(DrawImage.java:324)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.renderImageXform(DrawImage.java:392)
        at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DDrawImage.renderImageXform(D3DDrawImage.java:77)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.transformImage(DrawImage.java:264)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.scaleImage(DrawImage.java:124)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.scaleImage(DrawImage.java:1046)
        at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.scaleImage(ValidatePipe.java:207)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3127)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3067)
        at xmessenger.Overlay$ImageViewer.paintComponent(Overlay.java:143)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1055)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5232)
        at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
        at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5180)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4991)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
```

Here is my `Overlay` class:

```
public class Overlay extends JFrame {

        public Overlay(ArrayList<BufferedImage> imgs) {
            super();
            this.setUndecorated(true);
            getRootPane().setOpaque(true);
            pane = new JPanel();
            pane.setOpaque(false);
            add(pane);
            pane.setLayout(new CardLayout());

            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            imgWidth = (int) (dim.width * 0.7 + 0.4);
            imgHeight = (int) (imgWidth / 16 * 9 + 0.4);

            pos = 0;

            images = imgs;

            for (BufferedImage image: images) {
                addFrame(image);
            }

            ((CardLayout)pane.getLayout()).first(pane);
            pane.invalidate();

            this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                        setVisible(false);
                        dispose();
                    }
                    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        ((CardLayout)pane.getLayout()).previous(pane);
                        pos--;
                        if (pos < 0) pos = images.size() - 1;
                    }
                    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        ((CardLayout)pane.getLayout()).next(pane);
                        pos++;
                        if (pos > images.size() - 1) pos = 0;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
            });
        }

        public class ImageViewer extends JPanel {

            public ImageViewer(String src) {
                this.src = src;
                setOpaque(false);
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new URL(src));
                    int imgHeight = img.getHeight(observer);
                    if (imgHeight > 0) {
                        w = (int) (h * ((double) img.getWidth(null) / imgHeight));
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {}
            }

            public ImageViewer(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
                if (image == null) return;
                setOpaque(false);
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                System.out.println(width + "x" +  height);
                w = width;
                h = height;

                img = image;
                int imgHeight = img.getHeight(observer);
                if (imgHeight > 0) {
                    w = (int) (h * ((double) img.getWidth(null) / imgHeight));
                }
            }

            public ImageViewer(String src, int width, int height) {
                setOpaque(false);
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                w = width;
                h = height;
                this.src = src;
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new URL(src));
                    int imgHeight = img.getHeight(observer);
                    if (imgHeight > 0) {
                        w = (int) (h * ((double) img.getWidth(null) / imgHeight));
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {}
            }

            ImageObserver observer = new ImageObserver() {
                @Override
                public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
                    if (height == 0) return false;
                    w = (int) (h * ((double) width / height));
                    if (getParent() != null) getParent().repaint();
                    return true;
                }
            };

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if (img == null) return;
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                int x = (int) (getWidth() - w) / 2;
                int y = (int) (getHeight() - h) / 2;
                System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
                g2d.clearRect(x, y, w, h);
                g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h, null);
            }

            private int w;
            private int h;

            private Image img;
            private String src = null;
        }

        public void addFrame(BufferedImage image) {
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(new Color(12,12,12));

            pane.add(panel);
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(90, 90, 90, 90));

            ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(image, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(viewer);

            int number = pane.getComponentCount();
            JLabel status = new JLabel(number + " / " + images.size());
            status.setForeground(new Color(235, 235, 235));
            status.setFont(new Font("SegoeUI", Font.PLAIN, 17));
            status.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            panel.add(status, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        }

        public void prevImage() {
            ((CardLayout)pane.getLayout()).previous(pane);
            pos--;
            if (pos < 0) pos = images.size() - 1;
        }

        public void nextImage() {
            ((CardLayout)pane.getLayout()).next(pane);
            pos++;
            if (pos > images.size() - 1) pos = 0;
        }

        private int imgWidth = 0;
        private int imgHeight = 0;

        private ArrayList<BufferedImage> images;
        private int pos = 0;

        public void showContent() {
            try {
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);
                setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception error) {}
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
            try {
                images.add(ImageIO.read(new File("D:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/XMessenger/image.jpg")));
                images.add(ImageIO.read(new URL("http://popov654.pp.ru/copybox/photo.jpg")));
                images.add(ImageIO.read(new URL("http://popov654.pp.ru/copybox/DSCN2155.jpg")));
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
            Overlay o = new Overlay(images);
            o.showContent();
        }

        JPanel pane;
        JPanel panel;
    }
```

If I run it, it works OK. The problem appears when I create an instance from outside code:

```
   private void addHyperlinkListener(JTextPane pane) {
        pane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    String src = (String) e.getSourceElement().getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
                    System.err.println("Image src: " + src);
                    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) msgContent.getStyledDocument();
                    Element[] imgs = getElementsByTagName(HTML.Tag.IMG, doc);

                    ArrayList<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
                    ArrayList<String> srcs = new ArrayList<String>();
                    
                    int index = -1;
                    for (Element img: imgs) {
                        String source = (String) img.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
                        srcs.add(source);
                        try {
                            images.add(ImageIO.read(new URL(source)));
                        } catch (IOException ex) {}
                        if (!source.equals(src) && index < 0) {
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Overlay overlay = new Overlay(images);
                    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                        overlay.nextImage();
                    }
                    XMessengerApp.getMainWindow().getFrame().setVisible(false);
                    overlay.showContent();
                    
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

By the way, if I don't hide my current application frame, it keeps blinking through some areas of my overlay, which is also very strange. I thought that is the reason of failure (too many repaints because of that thing), but hiding it from the screen also does not help to avoid the errors.

Also when iI encounter this error, the blocks in my overlay's `CardLayout` stop reacting to key presses at all.

What am I doing wrong?

The application is not very heavy, the most "big" part of it is a JTextPane with HTML content, but that is ridiculously small: one 2-line paragraph of text and 3 images after it.

The app is made using the JDesktop framework. I'm running the code with JDK 7.

Also look here, please:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6567435
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5311994/How-to-fix-a-memory-leak-caused-by-bufferedimage-g

Maybe there is a bug leading to this in JDK/JRE? Except I am reading JPEGs, and not TIFFs, but with a much similar resolution.

Comment: JDK 7 is outdated. Please update your JDK to a later version like the LTS(JDK 17) or the latest version(JDK 19). It should work much better.

Comment: Follow this [article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19563-01/819-4438/gavou/index.html) after updating JDK to solve your problem.

Comment: I cannot do it for two reasons, unfortunately. 1) I need to support Windows XP in my app. 2) In JDK 8 and newer I have troubles with disabling auto-scale of GUI (I read a lot of the methods to disable it, but none of them works, at least on Windows 7). Tested at list on latest JRE 9 and the scaling-up cannot be disabled, that's why my GUI gets scaled twice (the first time by the OS itself, and then by JRE).

Comment: I added -Xmx512m argument in project run options, and it solved the issue, thank you. But why are 3 images of 3-8 megapixels each causing such high memory consumption that I need to bump up the standard memory usage limits? What if I will have 8-10 photos in some messages in my app?

Comment: May I asked a stupid question, because I am not very experienced in Java development. Why JDK versions are like 19-21 now, and when I google "latest JRE windows install" I get something like "Java JRE 8 Update 351"? Why is that, the version lines in JRE and JDK are completely different now?

Comment: Also, how can I test my app on latest version of Java on Windows 7, or should I use Windows 10/11 for that purpose? I'm asking that because now I have JRE 9 from 2018, and it hangs up when trying to update itself, then it says that no updates are available. Even though just before that it prompts to install a new version using the pop-up in system tray.

Comment: The reason why it takes so much space is that it has to load the classes(the functions, objects and etc) with the images(so it can be readily used in JDK).(I'm not a java expert, but I'm answering to the extent of my knowledge )

Comment: Okay, so if that's the case why it eats up to 380 Mb even without the overlay, then I should not worry about my images, if there will be more of them. Nice

Comment: (answer to May I asked a stupid question, because....)It's just a google thing. many people still use JDK 8(Even though replaced by JDK 17) and I'm not sure why(maybe for compatibility for jdk 8-19).

Comment: If you are looking for backward compatibility from windows XP to 10, I would suggest testing on windows 10. for windows 11 however(As far as I have developed apps for) You could test it separately on windows 11.

Comment: *the blocks in my overlay's CardLayout stop reacting to key presses at all.* You should not be using a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. There is no need to set the root pane opaque or the "pane" non-opaque. As I mention in one of your previous questions you don't need the ImageObserver. ImageIO returns a BufferedImage, so you can just use the getWidth() and getHeight() methods of that class.

Comment: I've read the text. I see why that approach is known as better one, but mine is working just fine when I don't have OOM exceptions. I am listening for KeyEvents on JFrame itself: `this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { ... })`

Comment: I published another one question on the same piece of code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74958620/failure-when-exiting-from-fullscreen-mode

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to increase the heap size for the VM:

```
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).